# ConTeXt: Putting a float in the margin upsets page layout

Tags: floats, context, layout

My MWE produces the output shown below. On page 2, the body text ignores the layout for the page, and flows below the bottom of the frame, down to the footer. I expected the text to stop at the bottom of the frame. How can I have the text stop at the bottom of the frame on page 2 ?

If I delete the `\placefigure` it works as I expect. If I change the first `dorecurse{3}` to `dorecurse{3}` to place the float higher in the margin on page 2, it works as I expect.

[image: float-layout]

```
\setuppapersize[A4][A3,landscape] \setuparranging[2SIDE] \showframe 

\definelayout[mypage][footerdistance=100mm, ]
\definelayout[odd][reset]   % ??
\definelayout[even][reset]

\starttext
\dorecurse{3}{\input{knuth} }   % change to \dorecurse{2} - it works  properly
\definelayout[2][mypage] 
\dorecurse{2}{\input{knuth} }
\placefigure [leftmargin]
     {} {\externalfigure[greybox][width=\leftmarginwidth]}
\dorecurse{5}{\input{knuth} }
\stoptext
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Running with `\EveryPar{\showthe\vsize}` gives some unexpected results, so I'm guessing that adding the float triggers the output routine at a time that interacts poorly with the `\definelayout[2][...]`. The same problem occurs with with both MkIV and MkXL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask for problems when messing with both layouts and these side floats (some chicken-egg problem, it seems). Some manual tweaking might solve your issue.

Does

```
\setuplayout
```

just before the `\placefigure` give you what you want?

Comment: Yes, that certainly fixed it. Thanks. And thanks for all your help with ConTeXt. I'm writing a history book with a lot of photos and diagrams. I use 6 different page layouts and place most images and captions on layers, with postponing as you suggested. I write the book in markdown in the app Obsidian, with some home-made extensions to handle the layouts and layers. I wrote some python to convert markdown to context. It all works much better than I expected. And much, much better than the desktop publishing app I was planning to use.